# How can I know if the sensor is based events or trigger?

Tags: android, events, triggers, sensors

I'm working on application that enumerate all the sensors that exist on the device and the user can register to each one he want to.

But I have an issue because not all the sensors are working with events (using `registerListener` method) there are some sensors using triggers, such as Significant Motion sensor.

I didn't find any way how to know if the sensor is working with events or trigger, [Google wrote](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/report-modes.html#one-shot):

> One-shot sensors are **sometimes** referred to as trigger sensors

So my question is, how can I know if I have to register to the sensor using `registerLisener` method or if I need to use `requestTriggerSensor`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getReportingMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getReportingMode())() method to determine the mode and then register the sensor accordingly. Also have a look on this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/report-modes.html#special) to see the differences between each mode.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you describe the differences within your answer here? Links can often become outdated if the URL changes

Answer (score 1):

I am super late to the party: There are 4 types of sensors, and you can use

```
thisSensor.getReporitngMode()
```

to check which type of sensor it is.

If it is [`REPORTING_MODE_ONE_SHOE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#REPORTING_MODE_ONE_SHOT), you should use `requestTriggerSensor()` instead. And it that listener will only be triggered once, but it is not hard to just reset it after each time it has been triggered.